# Can I file a patent application with two applicant corporations?

Tags: multiple, applicant

I would like to file a patent application that is jointly owned by two companies. Can both companies be applicants? Will both company names appear on patent publications?

Comment: This is not an answer - have they considered forming a jointly owned entity to hold the patent?

Comment: Good question, but no, the patent application is for some minor technology that both companies contributed to. They want to jointly own the patent and continue to go their separate ways. But both parties want to use the patent application in marketing so ideally both company names will appear on it.

Comment: Perhaps a cross licensing agreement?

Comment: The underlying business arrangement is fine. I'm just wondering about how this works in the application process. Can I have two applicants? Will both be listed on the patent application when it's published?

Comment: IF you look at the face of a recently granted U.S. patent you will see a spot for the applicant listed - that might be an inventor or it might be a company. It does not really indicate ownership. Then you will see assignee - that is the owner. Multiple assignee's might be easier and more relevant than more than one applicant.

Comment: I also think a marketing campaign centered on what it says on the face of a patent is odd.

Comment: George White, thanks for your comments. About your first comment, I'm interested in the initial patent publication rather than the grant publication. I have looked for examples where two applicants are listed but haven't found any. Nor could I find anything which said whether two applicants would be listed if there are two applicants. I know from the Application Data Sheet that you can specify multiple applicants, and I assume that all applicants will be listed, but would feel more comfortable if I saw an example. I may call up the USPTO helpline to confirm.

Comment: As to your second comment, it is a little odd to use patent publications in marketing but I think it will work very well in this case. We just want to make sure that the patent publication has both companies listed as applicants so anyone reading it knows that both companies are involved.

Comment: Are we talking about US patents? I’ve looked at some of my US applications and patents and only inventors and the assignee are listed. No “applicant”.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s301.html

Comment: Eric Shain, thanks for your comments. Yes, I'm talking about US patents. Perhaps in your case you did not identify any applicant and in that case the inventors are the applicants and are not separately listed. In my case I want both companies to be applicants and their names to both be listed. The link you gave does clarify ownership issues but in my case those issues are not a problem. I just want to be sure the names of both applicants appear. More and more I am confident that they do appear, but I would like to find an example of that.

Comment: If you want me to get a notification of your comment you should type the at symbol and select my name. In the examples I looked at, the applicant was my company who was also the assignee. Can you provide a like to an example where the applicant is listed on the published application?

Comment: Here is an example where the applicant is listed: pat2pdf.org/patents/pat20160231746.pdf

Comment: I was finally able to find what I was looking for: pat2pdf.org/patents/pat20160231745.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible for both the firms to be the applicant for a single invention. They will be considered as joint applicants. Name of both applicants will reflect in the patent if granted.

Comment: Could you clarify for which countries you know this to be true for?

Comment: As per general patent rules, It is true for most of the countries. I am sure for India. But this is a common thing in IPR world to have joint applicant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That answers the question about whether we can have two applicants. I know that you are correct because I have confirmed that I can list multiple applicants on the Application Data Sheet when applying for a patent. I am still looking for a published application that shows two or more applicants but haven't found one yet. I am pretty sure both applicants will be listed, though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Here is a few patent applications where two or more applicants are shown. US9132818B2, US8781701B2, US8734600B2, US8267757B2.

Comment: Thanks, but those are multiple assignees listed on a patent publication. I'm instead looking for multiple applicants listed on an application publication. I was finally able to find one: pat2pdf.org/patents/pat20160231745.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I did find an example of [a patent application publication that lists two applicants](http://pat2pdf.org/patents/pat20160231745.pdf). When applying for a patent, multiple applicants can be listed on the Application Data Sheet. Those applicants will be listed on the publication of the application and on the publication of any patent granted.